# Microsoft Outlook 2003 opens IE and FireFox for each HTML Link

Tags: firefox, email, microsoft-outlook, internet-explorer, html

Hello recently I got this pop-up dialog box asking me to browse for a browser for html links in my outlook emails.

So I navigated and selected Internet Explorer.
then I clicked on the HTML links in my emails and it just opens up my homepage in IE instead of the link I just clicked.

So I tried the registry fix.... and it works... it allows me to open the links with FireFox.
But now...

**Internet Explorer and Firefox open when I click any link in an e-mail with outlook!**

Does anyone know how to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: What is set as your default web browser? What happens if you click on links in other software (including other MSOffice programs)?

Comment: It seems to only be outlook. Thought a system restore fixes it. But that's a heavy move...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

System restore fixed it.